# Action from another xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have many xaml files and need to use some functions that I don't want to duplicate the code:

main.xaml.cs

```
 void gotoUrL(..){}

 void goroUsers(..){}

main.xaml
 <Image Tap="gotoUrl">..
```

How I can do this?
    something.xaml

```
<Image Tap="gotoUrl">
```

//gotoUrl referenced from main.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be that you write a separate helper class: `Helper.cs`.  (You can make it static). In `Helper.cs`, you can put all the functions that you dont want to duplicate. Then call that particular helper class function: `Helper.gotoUrl()` from the `gotoUrl()` method  of `main.xaml.cs` and `something.xaml.cs`. You code is not duplicated anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I suggest to use your way too. I did it hour ago, thought there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options with `UserControls`.. If you only need this for a particular Image which will remain the same, you can Simply Make a new `UserControl` with the Image inside of it.

If the functions may vary, you could make a `UserControl` like (Let's call it GoToUrlControl):

```
//all the xaml at the top of the file

x:Name="Control">

<Grid Tap="OnTapped">
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Body, ElementName=Control}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then, in the code behind, create a `DependencyProperty` (type `propdp` and hit `tab` twice)
Name it `Body`

Finally, to use it on any xaml page, you add the xaml reference, and something like

```
<myControls:GoToUrlControl>
   <GoToUrlControl.Body>
      <//put any content here here />
   </GoToUrlControl.Body>
</myControls:GoToUrlControl>
```

I'm not at a computer where I can give you fully working code, but this link should fill in the missing pieces.

[How to Implement a Dependency Property](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42203/How-to-Implement-a-DependencyProperty)